# Scikit-Learn: GridSearchCV giving same results for Linear Regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, grid-search

I have tried GridSearchCV and linear regression on the [Boston dataset](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_boston.html)

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
parameters = {'fit_intercept':('True', 'False'), 'normalize':('True', 'False'), 'copy_X':('True', 'False')}
clf3 = GridSearchCV(reg, parameters)
clf3.fit(X, y)
```

I am getting the same values for all the parameter permutations:

```
clf3.grid_scores_
[mean: -1.57573, std: 3.02988, params: {'normalize': 'True', 'copy_X': 'True', 'fit_intercept': 'True'},
 mean: -1.57573, std: 3.02988, params: {'normalize': 'False', 'copy_X': 'True', 'fit_intercept': 'True'},
 mean: -1.57573, std: 3.02988, params: {'normalize': 'True', 'copy_X': 'True', 'fit_intercept': 'False'},
 mean: -1.57573, std: 3.02988, params: {'normalize': 'False', 'copy_X': 'True', 'fit_intercept': 'False'},
 mean: -1.57573, std: 3.02988, params: {'normalize': 'True', 'copy_X': 'False', 'fit_intercept': 'True'},
 mean: -1.57573, std: 3.02988, params: {'normalize': 'False', 'copy_X': 'False', 'fit_intercept': 'True'},
 mean: -1.57573, std: 3.02988, params: {'normalize': 'True', 'copy_X': 'False', 'fit_intercept': 'False'},
 mean: -1.57573, std: 3.02988, params: {'normalize': 'False', 'copy_X': 'False', 'fit_intercept': 'False'}]
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

TIA

Comment: can you share sample dataset `X,y`

Comment: Can you do the same gridSearch without the `copy_x` parameter. And then print results.

Comment: Did it. No success

`[mean: -0.82518, std: 0.89872, params: {'fit_intercept': 'True', 'normalize': 'True'}, 
 mean: -0.82518, std: 0.89872, params: {'fit_intercept': 'True', 'normalize': 'False'},
 mean: -0.82518, std: 0.89872, params: {'fit_intercept': 'False', 'normalize': 'True'},
 mean: -0.82518, std: 0.89872, params: {'fit_intercept': 'False', 'normalize': 'False'}]`

Comment: `grid_scores_` is deprecated. The information you are looking for is in `cv_results_`. BTW, you should try to make your code a minimal working example, so people can more readily answer your question.

Comment: @chhibbz Did you resolve the problem? I have the same problem and am going to post a question myself on the same topic. GridSearchCV for me works on Classification and Clustering algorithms, yet gives me one continuous result and loops forever with Regression algorithms.